# How to choose optimal max concurrent value for flatMap

Tags: android, concurrency, rx-java2, flatmap

The application should download a lot of images from the network.
I would like to download this images in `parallel` as efficient as possible.
For achieving of parallel downloading the `flatMap` used, with providing of `maxConcurent` value.

```
    Disposable ds =
    dataManager.getAllImages()
        .flatMap(image -> Observable.zip(
        dataManager.processImageCaching(image.getFullSizeImage()),
            dataManager.processImageCaching(image.getThumbImage()),
            (Optional<CachedImage> fullSizeImage, Optional<CachedImage> thumbImage) -> {
                image.setFullSizeImageLocalPath(fullSizeImage.map(CachedImage::getFilePathInternal).orElse(null));
                image.setThumbImageLocalPath(thumbImage.map(CachedImage::getFilePathInternal).orElse(null));
                return image;
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()), MAX_CONCURRENT_THREADS)
        .doOnNext(dataManager::saveCachedImageToDb)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

The application works and downloads in parallel, but used value for `max concurrent` is probably not optimal and can not be universal.
I guess this value can be different for different devices.
Can someone give me an idea, how to choose the best max concurrent value based on device capabilities?
Thanks.
Note: current max concurrent value is 3

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * @param subscribeOn if not set, then creates new Thread (if there is room for new Thread)
 * @param observeOn if not set, then uses MainThread
 */
data class SchedulerProvider(val subscribeOn: Scheduler
                             = Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()))
                             , val observeOn: Scheduler = AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

I use something like this, it is based on available processors obviously. I am not sure if there is better way